# Prepone the joining day based on company’s holiday date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Somewhere i found a situation  where we have to find out the valid candidate joining date for each candidate. E.g if you check for CID the joining date is 10-01-2015 and as per the company’s holiday table they have holiday. So in this case we have to prepone the joining by one day. Hence for CJ10101 the valid joining date would be 08-01-2015 as they have holiday on 09-01-2015 also.

**Holiday Table:**

```
 ID       HolidayDate
 101  2015-01-10 00:00:00.000
 102  2015-01-09 00:00:00.000
 103  2015-02-19 00:00:00.000
 104  2015-03-11 00:00:00.000
 105  2015-04-11 00:00:00.000
```

**Candidate Joining Table:**

```
  CId             CJoiningDate
 CJ10101      2015-01-10 00:00:00.000
 CJ10104      2015-01-10 00:00:00.000
 CJ10105      2015-02-18 00:00:00.000
 CJ10121      2015-03-11 00:00:00.000
 CJ10198      2015-04-11 00:00:00.000
```

**Expected Output :**

```
 CId    CJoiningDate    ValidJoiningDate
CJ10101  10-01-2015       08-01-2015
CJ10104  10-01-2015       08-01-2015
CJ10105  18-02-2015       18-02-2015
CJ10121  11-03-2015       10-03-2015
CJ10198  11-04-2015       10-04-2015
```

**Table Creating Scripts** :

```
--Create Table
CREATE TABLE #Holidays
(
ID INT
,HolidayDate DATETIME
)
GO 
--Insert Data
INSERT INTO #Holidays(ID,HolidayDate)
VALUES
(101,'01/10/2015'),
(102,'01/09/2015'),
(103,'02/19/2015'),
(104,'03/11/2015'),
(105,'04/11/2015')


--Create Table
CREATE TABLE #CandidateJoining
(
CId VARCHAR(17)
,CJoiningDate DATETIME
)
GO 
--Insert Data
INSERT INTO #CandidateJoining(CId,CJoiningDate)
VALUES
('CJ10101','01/10/2015'),
('CJ10104','01/10/2015'),
('CJ10105','02/18/2015'),
('CJ10121','03/11/2015'),
('CJ10198','04/11/2015')
```

**Query :**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT MIN(HolidayDate) MinDate , MAX(HolidayDate) MaxDate FROM
    (
        SELECT * , DAY(HolidayDate) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HolidayDate ASC) rnk FROM #Holidays
    ) a GROUP BY rnk 
)
SELECT CId , CASE WHEN MinDate IS NULL THEN CJoiningDate ELSE MinDate -1 END CandidateJoining FROM #CandidateJoining j
LEFT JOIN CTE c ON j.CJoiningDate BETWEEN c.MinDate AND c.MaxDate
```

**Note:** This query gives me what we are expecting but looking for a better approach to get the result.

Comment: What is your SQL version? You have tagged both 2008 and 2012. Answers may vary depending on version

Comment: @uzi I've updated it. -:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query as an option. Does it perform better?

```
with cte as (   
    select
        *, minDate = min(HolidayDate) over (partition by grp)
    from (  
        select
            ID, HolidayDate, grp = sum(r) over (order by HolidayDate)
        from (
            select 
                *, r = iif(datediff(dd, lag(HolidayDate) over (order by HolidayDate), HolidayDate) = 1, 0, 1)
            from 
                #Holidays
        ) t
    ) t
)

select
    a.*, isnull(dateadd(dd, -1, q.minDate), a.CJoiningDate)
from
    #CandidateJoining a
    outer apply (
        select
            b.minDate
        from
            cte b
        where
            a.CJoiningDate = b.HolidayDate
    ) q
```

Edit:
This query should be a bit faster. But it assumes that you do not have a holiday rolling in the next year

```
with cte as (   
    select
        *, minDate = min(HolidayDate) over (partition by grp)
    from (  
        select 
            *, grp = day(HolidayDate) - row_number() over (order by HolidayDate)
        from 
            #Holidays
    ) t
)

select
    a.*, isnull(dateadd(dd, -1, b.minDate), a.CJoiningDate)
from
    #CandidateJoining a
    left join cte b on a.CJoiningDate = b.HolidayDate
```

Comment: thank you very much uzi .I've been observing your answers everywhere in SOW .You are helping out many users .Appreciate your efforts .Great -:).. Your query looks much complexity than what i posted .But i'm trying for easy and better than what i posted .

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind words :) `outer apply` easily can be rewritten with `left join` in this case. Actually second query is very similar to your query. Only difference is that you are using `between` in `join` to compare dates, while I am joining by exact match. Updated second query